# How to get hardware information in Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-xp, hardware-id

How to get hardware information (for example cpuId, biosId, diskId, baseId and videoId) in c++?

Can anyone give me an example visual studio project for this?

Comment: What platform? What API?

Comment: There is no way to do it in standard C++.  It has to be done in a platform specific way, so you need to specify which OS you're using.

Comment: My platform in windows xp and windows 2003 server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very different ways to get a disk id (serial number? volume id?) or a CPU ID or ... . I think you want to build a fingerprint of the computer.
The most comfortable way is to use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and access the [DMI](http://dmtf.org/standards/dmi) . See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) for a start.
See [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072(VS.85).aspx) for a hint how to get the mainboard serial number as an example.

Answer (score 3):

[GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will get you started with the CPU information.  Each subsystem generally has different query functions.

Answer (score 0):

The standard c++ don`t provide this for you. These api may be provided by os or hardware driver.

Comment: My platform in wondows xp and windows server 2003 X86.Can i get hardware info in this platforms?

Comment: Example:
xp: you can get information about disk. 
There are many apis:
GetDiskFreeSpace
GetVolumeInfomation